# Need help with the architecture for a penny bidding website

Tags: c#, asp.net, architecture

I'm trying to create a website similar to [BidCactus](http://www.bidcactus.com/) and [LanceLivre](http://www.lancelivre.com/).

The specific part I'm having trouble with is the seconds aspect of the timer.

When an auction starts, a timer of 15 seconds starts counting down, and every time a person bids, the timer is reset and the price of the item is increased by 0,01$.

I've tried using SignalR for this bit, and while it does work well during trials runs in the office, it's just not good enough for real world usage where seconds count. I would get HTTP 503 errors when too many users were bidding and idling on the site.

How can I make the timer on the clients end shows the correct remaining time?

Would HTTP GETting that information with AJAX every second allow me to properly display the missing time? That's a request each second!

And not only that, but when a user requests that GET, I calculate remaining seconds, but until the user see's that response, that time is no longer useful as a second or more might pass between processing and returning. Do you see my conundrum?

Any suggestions on how to approach this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple problems with the solution you described:

1. It is extremely wasteful.  There is already a fairly high accuracy clock built into every computer on the Internet.
2. The Internet always has latency.  By the time the packet reaches the client, it will be old.
3. The Internet is a variable-latency network, so the time update packets you get could be as high or higher than one second behind for one packet, and as low as 20ms behind for another packet.

It takes complicated algorithms to deal with #2 and #3.

**If you *actually* need second-level accuracy**

There is existing Internet-standard software that solves it - the [Network Time Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol).

Use a real NTP client (not the one built into Windows - [it only guarantees it will be accurate to within a couple seconds](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/939322)) to synchronize your server with national standard NTP servers, and build a real NTP client into your application.  Sync the time on your server regularly, and sync the time on the client regularly (possibly each time they log in/connect?  Maybe every hour?).  Then simply use the system clock for time calculations.

Don't try to sync the client's system time - they may not have access to do so, and certainly not from the browser.  Instead, you can get a reference time relative to the system time, and simply add the difference as an offset on client-side calculations.

**If you don't actually need second-level accuracy**

You might not really need to guarantee accuracy to within a second.

If you make this decision, you can simplify things a bit.  Simply transmit a *relative* finish time to the client for each auction, rather than an absolute time.  Re-request it on the client side every so often (e.g. every minute).  Their global system time may be out of sync, but the second-hand on their clock should pretty accurately tick down seconds.

If you want to make this a little more slick, you could try to determine the (relative) latency for each call to the server.  Keep track of how much time has passed between calls to the server, and the time-left value from the previous call.  Compare them.  Then, calculate whichever is smaller, and base your new time off that calculation.

I'd be careful when engineering such a solution, though.  If you get the calculations wrong, or are dealing with inaccurate system clocks, you could break your whole syncing model, or unintentionally cause the client to prefer the *higest* latency call.  Make sure you account for all cases if you write the "slick" version of this code :)

Answer (score 0):

One way to get really good real-time communication is to open a connection from the browser to a special tcp/ip socket server that you write on the server.  This is how a lot of chat packages on the web work.

Duplex sockets allow you to push data both directions.  Because the connection is already open, you can send quite a bit of very fast data across.

In the past, you needed to use Adobe Flash to accomplish this.  I'm not sure if browsers have advanced enough to handle this without a plugin (eg, websockets?)

Another approach worth looking at is long polling.  In concept, a connection is made to the server that just doesn't die, and it gives you the opportunity on the server to trickle bits of realtime data down to the clients.

Just some pointers.  I have written web software using `JavaScript <-> Flash <-> Python/PHP`, and was please with how it worked.

Good luck.

Comment: Web sockets are only barely supported at this point.  I'm pretty sure they're not in any official standard yet.  But an existing model that supports server -> client push is [the Comet model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming)).  Since this keeps a connection open, it might give the type of latency drop the OP is looking for.  *Edit* Oh, glossed over "long polling" in your answer.  Same thing ;)

Comment: I'm hesitant to use WebSockets at this point. And I mentioned I used SignalR (which uses long polling) and it doesn't work as expected. Tons of HTTP 503 errors if many users are online.